# 'HOME environement variable must be set and pint to a directory' Error

Tags: ruby, windows, installation

I'm trying to run Ruby on a Windows computer (don't ask...). When I type in 'irb' I receive:

```
$ irb
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rbreadline.rb:1097:in `<module:RbReadline>': HOME environment variable (or HOMEDRIVE and HOMEPATH) must be set and point to a directory (RuntimeError)
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rbreadline.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/readline.rb:10:in `<module:Readline>'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/readline.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/irb/input-method.rb:129:in `<module:IRB>'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/irb/input-method.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/irb.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems
```

Currently my HOME variable is set to %USERPROFILE%

I don't know if this is helpful

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.2.4p230 (2015-12-16 revision 53155) [i386-mingw32]
```

If there seems to be something apparent about how I should be setting this up, please tell me. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like this issue was resolved based on this: https://github.com/chef/chef-dk/issues/415. Try updating your gem